Probability distribution of numeric input variables for linear machine learning models
So I was reading this book : Data Preparation for Machine Learning by Jason Brownlee. And there was this block of text that was a bit confusing and I couldn't find any explanation. 
"For example, some algorithms assume each input variable, and perhaps the target variable,
to have a specific probability distribution. This is often the case for linear machine learning models that expect each numeric input variable to have a Gaussian probability distribution. This means that if you have input variables that are not Gaussian or nearly Gaussian, you might need to change them so that they are Gaussian or more Gaussian." 
I know that for any fixed value of $X$(input), $Y$ (target) is normally distributed as shown in the image below, is that the case with inputs also? 


In particular, my wiki answer addresses this. Briefly, there is no Gaussian assumption for the features. That book is incorrect on linear regression, and that makes me skeptical about its quality when it comes to more advanced topics.

@Dave thanks, I also want to know if there are other linear models other than the linear regression where this applies.

What would you mean by a linear model if not a linear regression?

@Dave Logistic Regression, LinearSVC ?

@Dave Linear / quadratic discriminant analysis assumes the features are Gaussian, no? The cited paragraph also does not explicitly refer to linear regression, it just says "some algorithms assume features follow a certain distribution, for example there are such things as linear models that assume the features are Gaussian," just worded somewhat poorly.

@ischmidt20 Yup, that's what I wanted to ask: linear regression and other linear models. Also, can you suggest some resources where I can read about this in detail..
